# Firebase Realtime Database Query in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to implement pagination on data stored in firebase realtime database. Reading some documentation I got to know that we can use query function given below.

```
const q = query(
  citiesRef, 
  orderBy("population"), 
  startAt(10000), 
  limitToFirst(10)
);
```

where we can define startAt based on orderBy key. But I don't have any field for orderBy instead I want to do pagiantion based on the key.
See the below database structure -

- Chapter1

  - Sloka1

    - Sloka
    - Translation
  - Sloka2

    - Sloka
    - Translation
  - Sloka3

    - Sloka
    - Translation
  - Sloka4

    - Sloka
    - Translation

So basically if you see my key is Sloka1, Sloka2 etc.. So how can I use startAt() in this condition.

I have tried using startAt() only, but it's giving me error.

I am expecting it should return like if startAt(2) and limitToFirst(2) then it should return Sloka2 and Sloka3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is `orderByKey()`, which is covered in the documentation on [ordering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data). Once you've ordered the data by its keys, you can then pass a key to `startAt`.

So in the example data structure you gave, that'd be:

```
const q = query(
  citiesRef, 
  orderByKey(), 
  startAt("Sloka2"), 
  limitToFirst(2)
);
```

This query will give you `Sloka2` and `Sloka3` as the results.

Comment: Ohh, I just missed because of the example using orderBy.
Thank you so much.